# Как сделать правильный запрос в БД?

Tags: php

Собственно:

```
$result = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."_stol_post WHERE id='{$fort1}'" );
```

У меня 3 таблицы - fort1, fort2, fort3 в одной из них правильный ID при котором выводятся посты, как сделать что он сразу проверял по всем трем сразу.

Comment: Почему в базе три однотипных таблицы?

Answer (score -1):

Можно написать запрос, используя `UNION ALL`, но во всех трех подзапросах должны быть одинаковые столбцы.

```
select
*
from 
  (select
     id, field1 
   from fort1
     union all
   select
     id, field1 
   from fort2
     union all
   select
     id, field1 
   from fort3) t
where t.id = '{$fort1}'
```

Comment: Не понял, если честно, у меня 3 таблицы fort1,fort2,fort3 - в них хранятся ID, либо в таблице есть ID, либо 0.

Comment: Я так понял что запись с требуемым `ID` может храниться только в одной из трех таблиц. `UNION ALL` объединяет результаты запросов, т.е. мы сразу ищем по трем таблицам.